# Was this review audit answer wrongly deleted?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

*Note: I have no affiliation with any of the parties involved with the question, answer, or deletion.*

I just ran into a review audit and failed it. [Here's the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875438/leafletjs-markers-move-on-zoom), and here's the deleted answer (with account names censored):

[image]

It looks as if neither reviewer actually read the full answer before voting for deletion. This may not be particularly well-written, but it certainly appears to be an answer, not a comment or another question.

Is there legitimate reason for this answer to have been deleted, or was this just the result of hasty reviews?

Comment: Thats a terrible answer, that should have had the first 2.5 sentences removed. Once you do that; it looks more like a guess than a real answer. By the letter of the law though, I could understand not deleting it (even though its crap).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree. It seems to be a case of "this worked for me, it might work for you too", which isn't the best type of answer, but I don't think that's reason to delete either. I could be missing something though, so I figure it's best to ask.

Comment: Looks like it got hammered by the First Posts review queue.

Comment: I failed a [similar audit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26593493) today. It had been deleted as link-only, but it did contain an excerpt from the site that appeared to attempt to answer the question. Not a *great* answer, but it should not have been deleted on the stated grounds and is not a good audit.

Comment: I would downvote both the answer and the question, but I don't feel it needed deletion.