# Possible "bad" audit in Late Answers queue?

Tags: discussion, support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Although there are a lot of question regarding *bad audits* ([mostly marked as duplicates](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276542/was-this-review-audit-answer-wrongly-deleted)), I don't really know where I can alert someone for a potential *bad audit* anywhere else but here on meta.

I don't really know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/13263333) is a good example of a *bad audit*, but for me, when reviewing that answer, although poorly formatted (and definitely not a thorough answer), I decided that it required no action (reason: because I had a "not an answer" flag declined in the past for an answer, indicating that "[not an answer] flags should not be used for technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer", so now I only flag answers when they are just unrelated junk).

So after the "STOP! LOOK! And LISTEN!" the answer comment (by a moderator) was shown, stating:

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. (...)

I understand why the comment was hidden in the audit (it would be too obvious that this was an audit), but without opening the answer to see that comment [or audit the user in question], there were no means in the review queue page to determine that the user posted identical answers on multiple questions.

Or, despite that reason, should this answer have been flagged anyway?

**EDIT 1:** *(in reply to whether comments are visible or not on audits)*

Based on [the answer of this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts), it seems (or at least, it is claimed) that comments are never shown on audits:

> An audit will not show the accurate score, **or any comments**, and may
>   change the displayed username and reputation;

Comment: Hmm I thought comments were shown in the Late Answers and Low Quality Posts reviews. They should be IMO. This situation (duplicate late answers copy-pasted around) happens quite frequently unfortunately. And, yeah, I don't think this is a good audit.

Comment: They usually are [visible]. But it seems that they can also be hidden in the audits.

Comment: *here were no means in the review queue page to determine that the user posted identical answers on multiple questions* - not entirely true, you can open the content in the site normally to spot the differences. Its more time consuming but its still a good habit to go see the entire truth in a quick scan.

Comment: @Gimby yes, I stated that before that sentence: "(...) but without opening the answer to see that comment (...) there were no means (...)". My point being: shouldn't the review system give you all the information you need, specially when being audited?